# Proving an Inequality?

Tags: integration

For :     $$n\in \mathbb{N} ^{\ast }-\left\{ 1\right\}$$
Prove :    $$\left( n!\right) !>\left( \left( n-1\right) !\right) ^{n!}$$

A hint given is:you can compare the numbers :

$$A=\int _{0}^{m}\ln xdx$$

$$B=\sum _{k=2}^{m}\ln \left( k\right)$$

Where m>2

I've compared A and B and found that $$A\leq B$$
   Here's what I've done :
     Let:$$p\in \mathbb{N} ^{\ast } $$
    $$\forall x\in \left[ p;p+1\right]$$ we have:

\begin{cases} \ln x\leq \ln \left( p+1\right) \\ \int _{1}^{m}\ln xdx=\sum _{p=1}^{m-1}\int _{p}^{p+1}\ln xdx\end{cases}

Thus:   $$\int _{1}^{m}\ln xdx\leq \sum _{p=1}^{m-1}\int _{p}^{p+1}\ln \left( p+1\right)dx$$
    And as we have:$$\sum _{p=1}^{m-1}\int _{p}^{p+1}ln\left( p+1\right) dx=\sum _{p=1}^{m-1}\ln \left( p+1\right)$$
   It means: $$\int _{1}^{m}\ln xdx\leq \sum _{k=2}^{m}\ln (k)$$

Therefore: $$A\leq B$$

At this point I gave up!

Comment: Try a proof by induction. Base case n=2 works. Then assume $(k!)!>(k-1)^{k!}$ for some n=k. Now  $(k+1!)!>k^{(k+1)!}$ is what we have to prove.

Comment: I'll try after a rest . This one drained my battery.

Comment: @Displayname: are you sure induction gives a simple way? The given inequality is indeed pretty tight once we switch to the logarithms of both sides and we divide those terms by $n!$.

Comment: I'm very close to solve it through that induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \int _{1}^{m}\ln xdx=\left[ x\ln x-x\right] _{1}^{m}$$
   $$=mlnm-m+1$$

Hence: $$mlnm-m+1\leq \sum _{k=2}^{m}\ln \left( k\right)$$

So:  $$exp(mlnm-m+1)\leq \exp \left( \sum _{k=2}^{m}\ln \left( k\right) \right) $$
     And since: $$\sum _{k=2}^{m}\ln \left( k\right)=ln2+ln3+...+lnm
                 =lnm!$$
      WE get :    $$ \exp \left( \ln \left( m\right) ^{m}\right)\cdot e^{-m}\cdot e\leq m! $$
         THus :     $$m^{m}\cdot \left( \dfrac {1} {e}\right) ^{n}.e\leq m!$$  $$\left( \dfrac {n} {e}\right) ^{m}.e.\left( \dfrac {m} {n}\right) ^{m}\leq m!$$
     Take $$m=n!$$ 
     Then   $$\left( n!\right) !\rangle \left( \left( n-1\right) !\right) ^{n!}.e\left( \dfrac {n} {e}\right) ^{n!}$$